# hibernate/jpa how to store relation between one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, annotations

I would like to store hierarchical folders in database.
F.e

```
@Entity
public class Folder {

int id
String name
Folder parentFolder

}
```

So if folder is in subfolder he should store information about parentFolder
If Folder is in root/top folder, it dosnt have any parentFolder, so there will be null

How should I set hibernate using annotation to achive this?

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="common__Role")
public class Role {

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;

/**
 * Parent Role id.
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
public Role role;

/** The name. */
@Constraints.Required
public String name;
```

Comment: That is a `@OneToMany` nd a `@ManyToOne`relation so you should handle this as such.

Answer (score 2):

This should be your Entity ..

```
@Entity
@Table("FOLDER")
public class Folder {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE })
  @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
  private Folder parentFolder;


  //Getter and Setter
}
```

Maybe you should follow [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)

***How to persist ManyToOne***

```
Folder f= new Folder();
f.setName("name");

Folder fParent = entityManager.find(Folder .class, 1L);
f.setParent(fParent);

entityManager.persist(f);
```

See also [this tutorial](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToOneCascadePersist.htm)

Comment: I've tried, but Your solution didnt resolve problem. When I add another Folder, and I am choosing parentFolder there is no error. But there is no relation id in database between child-parent

Comment: To save a relationship is needed a JoinColumn else does not work. You should add a column PARENT_ID. I suggest you a simple ManyToOne relationship using JPA.

Comment: " You should add a column PARENT_ID" - did You mean database? I've done this, but there goes only nulls. There is no relation

Comment: If you want persist everything you should add a cascade on relationship for the action that you needed. E.G. `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE })`

Comment: It didnt helped. Remember that I have relation inside one entity

Comment: To help you better, Can you add the code that you used to persist the entity?